# HttpClient get working with a subscription but not with pipe angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm currently having an issue in my angular app where I am fetching a url and if I just subscribe directly to the observable and print the value to the console I can see its working.  However, if I instead utilize pipe(map()) for some reason it isn't firing.

```js
  public getDrugList(drugName: string, depth: number = 1) {
    
    const url = '<my-url>';
    this.httpClient.get<Model[]>(url, {

      params: {
        depth: depth.toString(),
        code: '<my-code>',
        drugName: drugName.trim(),
      }
    }).pipe(map(models => {
      
      return models.flat();
    }), map(models => {

      const nodes = this.getNodesFromModels(models);
      const edges = this.getEdgesFromModels(models);
      console.log(edges);
      console.log(nodes);

      return {
        nodes: nodes,
        edges: edges
      };
    }));

  }
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the thing with `Observables`. They only "take flight" if you subscribe to them.

You can either do:

```
 public getDrugList(drugName: string, depth: number = 1) {
    
    const url = '<my-url>';
    this.httpClient.get<Model[]>(url, {

      params: {
        depth: depth.toString(),
        code: '<my-code>',
        drugName: drugName.trim(),
      }
    }).pipe(map(models => {
      
      return models.flat();
    }), map(models => {

      const nodes = this.getNodesFromModels(models);
      const edges = this.getEdgesFromModels(models);
      console.log(edges);
      console.log(nodes);

      return {
        nodes: nodes,
        edges: edges
      };
    })).subscribe(result => console.log(result));

  }
```

Or make this method return the observable:

```
 public getDrugList(drugName: string, depth: number = 1): Observable<any> { // change any to what it is returning
    
    const url = '<my-url>';
    return this.httpClient.get<Model[]>(url, {

      params: {
        depth: depth.toString(),
        code: '<my-code>',
        drugName: drugName.trim(),
      }
    }).pipe(map(models => {
      
      return models.flat();
    }), map(models => {

      const nodes = this.getNodesFromModels(models);
      const edges = this.getEdgesFromModels(models);
      console.log(edges);
      console.log(nodes);

      return {
        nodes: nodes,
        edges: edges
      };
    })).subscribe(result => console.log(result));

  }

....
this.getDrugList().subscribe(result => console.log(result));
....
```

In essence, you have to subscribe to the observable and it's not like a promise where a promise takes flight whether or not you call `.then` or `await` on it.